# Filter results from a serialized string to use on statistics

Tags: php, database, sql, query-string

I need to get the values from a serialized string, to use it on some statistics. I already got that info in other pages to show some content, but I have no idea why I'm having this problem now.

The DB has a table called `wj_db7_forms` (I'm using a WordPress plugin to log the inputs on a form).

And the column with the info I need is on `form_value`.

Cleaning the content of the column, there is a part with `s:4:"city";s:6:"boston"`.

I want to get all the forms, and on every one, get the value for `city`. That value can have any lenght, because it's an open input.

I tried a lot of ways, but none worked.

I get erros like

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'city' (T_STRING)

or don't get errors at all, but the variable seems empty, etc.

I tried `unserialize`, `array_pop`, `print_r`, `echo`, everything...

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'db7_forms';
$results    = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT form_value FROM $table_name WHERE form_post_id = 6062", OBJECT );
$form_data  = unserialize( $results[0]->form_value );
print_r($form_data);
?>
```

With that code, I get all the info from the form, but I get everything, including info from other columns... And only from one form. I need to get from all the forms with that 'form_post_id' that are inside 'wj_db7_forms' table.

The content inside the 'form_value' of one of the forms is here: https://pastebin.com/e6LzJzLS

$form_data['city'] works now. But I need to get the values for all the forms. It only returns one for me.

Comment: What is the exact value of that column?

Comment: The value is:
https://pastebin.com/e6LzJzLS

I'll update the question with new info.

Comment: This is the output of `$results[0]->form_value`? Did you change some parts of that value you posted here (because it is not properly serialized now)? Anyway, are you sure `$form_data['city']` doesn't work? What does your `print_r()` return?

Comment: $form_data['city'] works now.
But I need to get the values for all the forms. It only return one for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the form saves a large serialized array in the database. Now since you have multiple forms, you need to iterate over the result from `get_results`, `unserialize` the column and then access the `city` key.

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'db7_forms';
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT form_value FROM $table_name WHERE form_post_id = 6062", OBJECT );
// iterate over results
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $data = unserialize($result->form_value);
    // now the city is in $data['city']
}
```

Comment: It's probably right, but I ahve more than 1 form getting saved. That's why I used the 'form_post_id', cuz I need only the forms from that ID. (the 'form_post_id' isn't unique, all the forms sent from the same page, have the same 'form_post_id', but different ID's

Comment: @MarceloHenriquesCortez Okay, sorry I am not familiar with that plugin. So if you keep the query the same and only add the foreach, does it work?

Comment: Got an error trying to place just the foreach: 
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\tophomestay\wp-content\plugins\contact-form-cfdb7\inc\add-ons.php on line 36
Array

Comment: Ok, now it doesnt show any erro msg, works, but it's still showing only 1 result

Comment: And now its working showing all. Thnx =)